# Flutter How To Update/Add Value to a Key in a Map<K,V>

Tags: dart, flutter

Currently I have a map that looks like this to send emails via an API:

```
Map body = {"personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "$receiverEmail"
        }
      ],
      "dynamic_template_data": {
        "EmployeeName": "$employeeName",
        "EmployeeID": "$employeeID",
        "PatientName": "$patientName",
        "ProviderName": "$providerName",
        "TreatmentDate": "$treatmentDate",
        "Diagnosis": "$diagnosis"
      }
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "$userEmail"
  },
  "template_id": "$templateID"
};
```

I am planning to use this structure with 2 forms of emails and for that to happen I need to update/add values under the **dynamic_template_data** key.

Therefore I am trying to find out how I could update/add value to that specific key. I found a function called **Map.update()** but I am unsure as how to properly use it. How do I approach this problem?

Comment: You don't need to use string-interpolation if the value is known to be a string. (just `employeeName` instead of `"$employeeName"`)

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer will keep that in mind next time. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

Just assign a new value to a specific key to update.

```
body['personalizations'][0]['dynamic_template_data']['EmployeeName'] = 'John Doe';
```

or

```
body['personalizations'][0]['dynamic_template_data']['Salary'] = 5000.00;
```

another example to do an assignment only if it doesn't exist yet

```
(body['personalizations'][0] as Map).putIfAbsent('Salary', () => 5000.00);
```

Comment: Will give this a try. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.update()` and `Map.updateAll()` is a predefined function for this.

```dart
Map<String, bool> filterMap = {
    'All': true,
    'Open': false,
    'Inprocess': false,
    'Resolved': false,
    'Closed': false,
  };
```

just use this to set all value pairs to false :-
 `filterMap.updateAll((key, value) => value = false);`

OUTPUT :

```
[MapEntry(All: false), MapEntry(Open: false), MapEntry(Inprocess: false), MapEntry(Resolved: false), MapEntry(Closed: false)]
```

In case you want to change a single value :-

```
filterMap.update(filterMap.keys.toList()[index]),(value) => value = true);
```

(`filterMap.keys.toList()[index]`) -> this is key name. I have used it in list. So, to find a element on which user tapped, I have used this. You can give a key name there.

`filterMap.update('Open'),(value) => value = true);`

OUTPUT :

```
 [MapEntry(All: false), MapEntry(Open: true), MapEntry(Inprocess: false), MapEntry(Resolved: false), MapEntry(Closed: false)]
```